# Crystal Report CurrentValues.Add adds same value over and over

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, reportviewer, crystal-reports-xi

I'm tying to use `.split` to pass multiple values to a multiple value enabled parameter.  If I select 4 items, 4 values will be passed into the crystal report but all 4 will have the same value of the last item (i.e. if I select `1,2,3,4` the crystal report receives `4,4,4,4`).

```
ParameterField f1 = CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo["Emp Id"];
ParameterDiscreteValue v1 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
string LBL1 = Request.QueryString["LBL1"].ToString();
string[] LBL1split = LBL1.Split(',');

foreach (string item in LBL1split)
{
    v1.Value = item;
    f1.CurrentValues.Add(v1);
}
```

Is the new value overridding the existing items in `.CurrentValues`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should notice that you are passing a class to the `CurrentValues.Add` method

so the only thing you have to change is this:

put `ParameterDiscreteValue v1 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();` to the loop

```
ParameterField f1 = CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo["Emp Id"];
string LBL1 = Request.QueryString["LBL1"].ToString();
string[] LBL1split = LBL1.Split(',');

foreach (string item in LBL1split)
{
    ParameterDiscreteValue v1 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
    v1.Value = item;
    f1.CurrentValues.Add(v1);
}
```